# How to fetch data from a table and print it in javascript table(php script)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

[this is the javascript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b57PO.jpg)

[this is the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0SEm.jpg)

I have a table name`employee` with `id`,`emp_number`,`emp_name`, i want to fetch data from `employee` table and want to print to this javascript code. using custom php script ,I have no idea how to fetch those data into that javascript box.
Help me with your knowledge guys

```js
<script src="js/jquery.columns-1.0.min.js"></script> 
<script>
   //example 1 
   $('#example1').columns({
    data: [
     {'Emp. Number': 1, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 2, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 3, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 4, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 5, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 6, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 7, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 8, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 9, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 10, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' },
     {'Emp. Number': 11, 'Name':'Demo Name', 'Numbers':'+91 00000' }
    ]
   });
   
   
   $('#theme').change(function() {
    $('link').attr('href', 'css/'+$(this).val());
   })


  </script>
```

Comment: Please share your code in question not in link. And also share your effort .

Comment: please check i shared my code

Comment: If you are creating this use double quotes like `"Emp. Number"` instead of `'Emp. Number'`

Answer (score 0):

you can convert data array php to json javascript instant

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: give me some example, i'm just a beginner

Comment: $('#example1').columns({
    data: [<?=json_encode($array);?>] like this

Answer (score 0):

```
You can encode the data array into json and return to the jquery script as follows:

$data=database query return result set;
json_encode($data);

in jquery code (inside script) just use the get method with the url of the page..
$getJSON('url',function(data){
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   $('table tbody').append('<tr>');
   $('table tbody').append(data[i].id); // same as other columns you want to append
   $('table tbody').append('</tr>');
}
});

and in html code just create a simple html code for table with column names.
```